# Back face culling + GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP?

Tags: opengl

If I've got 4 vertices which I render in this order:

```
2-3
|\|
0-1
```

using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` and then I enable back-face culling with the front face defined as CCW, then would the bottom-left triangle be facing me and the other one not? If so, what's the most efficient way of rendering a square so that both faces are visible? Do I have to use `GL_TRIANGLES` and pass down 6 vertices instead of 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strip primitive does the right thing with respect to backface culling. You can think of the tris' winding order as being managed so that the order is consistent for each triangle in the strip - e.g. you can think of the GPU rendering (0,1,2), (2,1,3) ...

Answer (score 4):

All triangles in triangle strip maintain same direction/winding order. 
They don't flip one after another. So either both triangles will be towards you or away from you (assuming your primitive is flat square shape (that is convex and doesn't intersect itself) where all vertices belong to same plane).

P.S. You know, you COULD render trianglestrip primitive in OpenGL application with culling enabled and see for yourself.

Comment: Or you could read documentation: http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec42.core.20120119.pdf (page 22)

Answer (score 3):

The "does the right thing" or "maintain same winding order" description in the other answers is not explicit enough. To show how exactly the winding order is defined, let me quote the spec, namely its Figure 10.2 (in OpenGL≥4.3, or Figure 2.3 in older versions).

> [image: Figure 10.2]
>
> Figure 10.2. (a) A triangle strip. (b) A triangle fan. (c) Independent triangles. The numbers give the sequencing of the vertices in order within the vertex arrays. Note that in (a) and (b) triangle edge ordering is determined by the first triangle, while in (c) the order of each triangle’s edges is independent of the other triangles.